# Descarregar conteudo da session numa classe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um site que funciona assim. Ele possui 6 passos. Roteiros, Aéreo, Hotéis, Serviços, Resumo e Pagamento. Cada passo desse, eu gravo numa session. Após a escolha de cada produto na session, é criada outra session e passado adiante. Bem, no passo resumo, eu tenho lá meu carrinho de compras. Eu criei uma classe carrinho, com as propriedades referentes a cada item relevante em cada passo, tipo: IdRoteiro, IdAereo, ValorAereo, ValorHotel, IdHotel, DataRoteiro, DataAereo e assim por diante. Agora, como eu faço para desacarregar cada item das sessions nas propriedade da classe Carrinho? Como seria a melhor forma?

Então, ainda tenho bastante dúvidas nisso. Sei q é primário para alguns, mas tenho dúvida. Como é um passo-a-passo, eu preciso no próximo passo pegar algumas informações, que estão em um type hidden no cshtml anterior. Entendi o que o reiksiel disse, mas ainda me complico com coisas fáceis. Falta pegada.

Answer (score 2):

### Agora, como eu faço para descarregar cada item das sessions nas propriedade da classe Carrinho? Como seria a melhor forma?

Supondo que você tenha serializado a classe inteira na session dessa forma:

```
Session["IdCarrinho"] = carro;
```

Ficaria algo assim:

```
Carrinho carro = (Carrinho) Session["IdCarrinho"];
```